# Update name in inputfield in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am creating a template maker and it's working fine. My supervisor asked me to make a autofill button for her and a few other persons. If she want's to make a template, her name will be automaticly filled in at the inputfield just by clicking a button.

The code for the inputfield for the name looks like this:

```
[sg.Text("Name"), sg.InputText(key="NAME", do_not_clear=False)]
```

And the button for the template for 'Person-1' looks like this:

```
[sg.Button('Template Person-1')]
```

The while loop looks like this:

```
 while True:
        event, values = spv_window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
            break
        elif event == 'Template Person-1':
            spv_window['NAME'].Update(values['NAME'], 'Person-1')
        elif event == "Maak template":
            doc.render(values)
            output_path = Path(values["-IN-"]) / f"{values['NAME']}-{values['TOPIC']}.docx"
            doc.save(output_path)
            sg.popup("Template gegenereerd", f"zie: {output_path}")
```

Can someone explain to me what's going wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `values['NAME']` is for the content of the `InputText` element, and it is not necessary if you want to update the content of the `InputText` element with a specified name. Try `spv_window['NAME'].Update('Person-1')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Settings to remember previously entered values

Another approach to having an "Auto-fill" button is to fill the value with whatever the last entered value is.  This will basically customize the GUI for each person with you needing to make a special feature or save a special set of settings for each person.

In this example, the "Name" field defaults to the last entered value.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('My Form')],
            [sg.Text('Name:'), sg.Input(default_text=sg.user_settings_get_entry('-name-', ''), key='-NAME-')],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Go':
        # Save the Name entered and use it next time to auto-fill
        sg.user_settings_set_entry('-name-', values['-NAME-'])

window.close()
```

[image]

If it's a field that the person is unlikely to change, then it'll keep being set to the same value every time the program is executed.

Another approach is to make templates.  If you do, then the PySimpleGUI User Settings API can still be handy for implementing this feature.

Comment: This is even better than my idea. Thank you very much!